# A better way to make pytorch code agnostic to running on a CPU or GPU?

Tags: python, gpu, cpu, pytorch

The Migration [guide](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-0_4_0-migration-guide/) recommends the following to make code CPU/GPU agnostic:

```
> # at beginning of the script
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
...
# then whenever you get a new Tensor or Module
# this won't copy if they are already on the desired device
input = data.to(device)
model = MyModule(...).to(device)
```

I did this and ran my code on a CPU-only device, but my model crashed when fed an input array, as saying it was expecting a CPU tensor not a GPU one.  Somehow my model was automatically converting the a CPU-input array to a GPU array.  Finally I traced it down to this command in my code:

```
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).to(device)
```

Even though I convert the model to 'cpu', the nn.DataParallel overrides this.  The best solution I came up with was a conditional:

```
if device.type=='cpu':
    model = model.to(device)
else:
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).to(device)
```

This does not seem elegant.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)
model = model.to(device)
```

?

You don't need `DataParallel` if you have only one GPU.

Comment: That's interesting.  I hadn't realized `DataParallel` was only for multi-GPU.